# Declaring extra arguments for a tkinter widget event handler

Tags: python, tkinter

On [New Mexico Tech website](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/extra-args.html) on how to declare extra arguments for an event handler, the following example was provided.

```
def __createWidgets(self):
    …
    self.cbList = []    # Create the checkbutton list
    for i in range(10):
        cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, …)
        self.cbList.append(cb)
        cb.grid( row=1, column=i)
        def handler(event, self=self, i=i):   ## 1
            return self.__cbHandler(event, i)
        cb.bind('<Button-1>', handler)
    …
def __cbHandler(self, event, cbNumber):
    …
```

> Remark ##1: These lines define a new function handler that expects
>   three arguments.  The first argument is the Event object passed to all
>   event handlers, and the second   and third arguments will be set to
>   their default values—the extra arguments we  need to pass it.

**Questions:**

1. Is the `self=self` arguement in `def handler(...)` needed to pass
   "self" into the event handler `de __cbHandler(...)`? Is "self" not inherently present in the event handler by default?
2. I have written a test code to study my question. With or
   without the argument `self=self`, the test code works the same. Is there an event handling scenario where declaring the `self=self` argument compulsory/necessary?

**Test code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    import tkinter as tk # Python 3 tkinter modules
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk # Python 2 tkinter modules

class NewListbox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, lb_values1, lb_values2):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.lb_values = tk.StringVar() 
        self.lb_values.set(lb_values1) 
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=self.lb_values)
        self.listbox.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # Having self=self and removing seems to make no difference.
        # self, appears to be pass on to the method def _update().
        def handler(event, self=self, values2=lb_values2): 
            return self._update(event, lb_values2)
        self.listbox.bind("<Button-1>", handler)

    def _update(self, event, newvalues):
        self.lb_values.set(newvalues)


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew') 
        nlist1 = ['Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary']
        nlist2 = ['Sarah', 'Jane', 'Oscar', 'Walley', 'Faith']
        self.lb = NewListbox(self, nlist1, nlist2)
        self.lb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

**Original Approach (see below):**

Advantage: Easy to implement.

Cost of Implementation: Increase the number of attribute to a widget.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    import tkinter as tk # Python 3 tkinter modules
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk # Python 2 tkinter modules

class NewListbox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, lb_values1, lb_values2):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.lb_values = tk.StringVar() 
        self.lb_values.set(lb_values1) 
        self.lb_values2 = lb_values2   # create new attribute to store lb_values2
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=self.lb_values)
        self.listbox.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.listbox.bind("<Button-1>", self._update)

    def _update(self, event):
        self.lb_values.set(self.lb_values2) #load new attribute.


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew') 
        nlist1 = ['Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary']
        nlist2 = ['Sarah', 'Jane', 'Oscar', 'Walley', 'Faith']
        self.lb = NewListbox(self, nlist1, nlist2)
        self.lb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can use lambda: `bind("<Button-1>", lambda event:self._update(event, lb_values2))` but I would use  `self.lb_values2 = lb_values2` and then `bind` doesn't need extra argument.

Comment: @furas Yes, I agree with you the latter approach is easiest to do. I have been doing that usually. But in situation where I want to avoid declaring too many attributes to the widget and yet be able to pass variables to event methods, I thought this approach by NMT (and the use of lambda which you have mentioned) make sense. Can you answer my posted questions? Appreciate any help given to clarify my understanding.