# struggle with Event and Definitions

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to write a bind counter programm but I had problems with the variable 'r'. Because without a 'r' in the line: def callback(event,r): I was facing with an error which is called LocalBoundError. I've searched a bit, and learned that I should use my parameter writing in def(). Therefore, I've tried it. But it does not work, because there is already a parameter, event. Do you have any idea what I should do ?

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()    
r = 0

def callback(event,r):    
    r = r+1    
    print(r)    
    top.mainloop()

top.bind("<Button-1>",callback,r)    
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: please fix the formatting of your code. There are tools in the editor that make that easy. Look for the button that looks like `{}`.

Comment: The answers are mentioned in my question and @furas comment [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41800868/5722359) .

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda to pass the extra parameter `r` to the `callback` function

```
top.bind("", lambda event: callback(event, r))
```

You may also need to make `r` a `global` variable so that it will change permenantly after the function

Comment: No problem at all :)